# Compare Variable with first name in array HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Just working on a test, been given the following task which to me makes no sense.

Would anyone be able to assist? Thanks

**Using JavaScript create an array called names.**

1. Add 10 names to the array. Save the file as names.txt
2. Create a new html document and save it as names.html.
3. Create an external JavaScript file called names.js.
4. Within the JavaScript file add your names array created.
5. Declare a new variable x with a value of one name in your array.
6. Write an ‘if’ statement to compare variable x with the first name in your array.
7. Create a function to generate an alert message depending on the comparison (ie. ‘This is the same name’ or ‘These names are different’).
8. Ensure your web page links to the JavaScript file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc., and try to do the work yourself**. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, post your code and a description of the problem (after doing research and [searching](/help/searching), of course), and people will be glad to help.

Comment: Found this page, not too sure if it is relevant to this? https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/jsref_every.asp
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are taking this test because you are learning programming, correct?

If your answer is Yes then please try to write it by yourself. Otherwise you'll give the answer and go to the next stage BUT you won't learn a thing!

On the other hand, if your answer is No, search on the net and you'll find the solution for sure. After that it's just copy-paste.

Comment: yes and no ahah 
It is a theory test for programming course that we had to take home but the question is abit confusing. I'm guessing the way to do it would be have a button that's function is to compare the value if = name then return a message saying it's the same?

Comment: or a loop that goes through every name each click of the button and says if the name is same or different

Comment: If you follow the steps one by one and check the tutorial you'll make it.
First place of an array is 0, this is the tip.